# How to replace all the property names of a json object

Tags: javascript, json, rename

I would like to change all the property names of a json object

```
const obj = {
  "key1": "Value1",
  "key2": "Value2",
  "key3": "Value3"
}

// I would like to have something like this : 

obj = {
  "renamedKey1": "Value1",
  "renamedKey2": "Value2",
  "renamedKey3": "Value3"
}
```

---

Sorry I should have been more specific but the names of the properties are not alike at all.

For example ...

```
const obj = {
  "country": "Value1",
  "area": "value2",
  "color_flag": "value3"
}

// I would like to have something like this : 

obj = {
  "pays": "Value1",
  "superficie": "Value2",
  "couleur_drapeau": "Value3"
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the original `keyX` name have any bearing on the name of the `renamedKeyX`? How does the former become the latter?

Comment: I'll ask again, how do the original keys become the new keys? What is the transformation process?

Comment: Do you only need to support _English to French_ key translation or do you need to support other localisation as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to translate the keys (from English to French).

I would recommend some sort of translation table. This is a very simple example

```js
const obj = {
  "country": "Value1",
  "area": "value2",
  "color_flag": "value3"
}

const i18n = {
  fr: {
    country: 'pays',
    area: 'superficie',
    color_flag: 'couleur_drapeau'
  }
}

const translateKeys = (obj, lang) => Object.entries(obj).reduce((tr, [ key, val ] ) => ({
  ...tr,
  [i18n[lang] && i18n[lang][key] || key]: val
}), {})

console.info(translateKeys(obj, 'fr'))
```

This produces a new object by taking the keys, performing a lookup in the translation table and assigning them with their corresponding values to the new object literal. If the language or translation key cannot be found, the original object key is used.

Answer (score 3):

You could grab the entires of the object and then [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) them to the new `[key, value]` pair entries (with `key` renamed). Then use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to build the new object for you from the entries:

```js
const obj = {
  "key1": "Value1",
  "key2": "Value2",
  "key3": "Value3"
}

const res = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => ['renamed'+k, v]));
console.log(res);
```

If you [can't support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries#Browser_compatibility) Object.fromEntries(), you could use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) as an alternative by mapping your entries to objects:

```js
const obj = {
  "key1": "Value1",
  "key2": "Value2",
  "key3": "Value3"
}

const res = Object.assign({}, ...Object.keys(obj).map(k => ({['renamed'+k]: obj[k]})));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Both of these are really clever but I particularly like the second one.

Answer (score 0):

On modern browsers, check out [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```
const newObj = {};
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(originalObj)) {
  newObj['renamed' + key] = value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
      obj[key] = 'renamedKey1'
   }
}
```

Though it's not recommended to change the value of the json. You can create a copy of that object and work with it.

```
let newObj = {}
let i = 0
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
      newObj['renamedKey' + i] = value;
      i++
   }
}
```